# Am I using this [^{\}]+(?=}) regular expression correctly on TypeScript

Tags: regex, typescript, curly-braces

Hello I am trying to get the values surrounded by curly braces "{value}". I am using this regular expression [^{}]+(?=}) correctly?

```
let url = "/{id}/{name}/{age}";

let params = url.match('[^{\}]+(?=})');
if(params != null){

  params.forEach(param => {
    console.log(param);
  });
}

// expected output
id
name
age

//actual output
id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the search stops after the first match.

You should use a regex literal delimited by slashes (like: `/regex/`), not a string delimited by quotes (like: `'string'`).

And then you should add the `/g` flag to the end of it, which means "global". This lets it search through the whole string to find all matches.

```js
let url = "/{id}/{name}/{age}";

let params = url.match(/[^{\}]+(?=})/g);
//                                   ^ do a global search
if(params != null){

  params.forEach(param => {
    console.log(param);
  });
}
```

From MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

> The "g" after the regular expression is an option or flag that performs a global search, looking in the whole string and returning all matches.